# AWS and Route53 : Certificate not validating

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-route53

I've a domain registered with route53 and I'm trying to validate certificate. I did press on "request" on the AWS Certificate Manager (ACM), then I clicked on "Created records in Route 53" and when I go into the Hosted Zone of this domain, the cname record is present. But more than a day later, the certificate is not validated.

[image]

[image]

And I've been able to obtaint a AWS certificate for another domain outside Route53, so usually I'm able to make this kind of thing works... :(

Please advise. Thank you very much!

Comment: Since you've made everything blurry you're going to have to ask AWS support for help.

Comment: First thing I would do it make sure the DNS records are being returned from a public DNS provider (Google, OpenDNS, CloudFlare, whatever). You can use CLI tools to do this or you can find a web site that can do it as well. 
If the records are not being returned, then go back to your registrar and make sure the registrar's record for name servers matches the entry at the top of the Route53 record (not the NS record shown in the screenshot, though that should match as well). Remember creating a hosted zone in Route53 is not the same as registering a domain.

Comment: @tim-p You were right! Thanks! 
In fact, I found the solution my problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58604183/19573176

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my problem : NS from the domain should match with the NS in the hosted zone, as detailled here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58604183/19573176